# Do something only if user types 'x' into input first

Tags: ruby

I'm making a text based adventure game. My code is as follows:

```
case move
when "go north"
puts "you hurl yourself at the now weakened door".
when "attack"
puts "You break the weakened door!"
```

I want `"attack"` to `puts` the broken door message only if the user types `"go north"` before that. If they type `"attack"` before `"go north"`, I want it to say something else. How can I get ruby to check if a specific command has been input into a case statement?

EDIT:

This is my updated code:

states = []

```
case move
when "help"
  help
when "quit"
  quit
when "inventory"
  @inventory
when "go north"
  puts "You hurl your shackled self toward the door. The chains cut into your wrists     and ankles, but you seem to be making progress."
  states << :north # add the state to the pile
  when 'attack chains'
     if states.include? :north # does our pile of state contains :in_north
      puts "You slam your shackled fists against the wall. You broke the chains!"
    else
      puts "You smash your shackled fists on the ground. Nothing happens."
    end
when "go south"
  puts "Your back shivers against the cold surface of the stone wall."
when "go east"
  puts "You tug to your right, but the chains hold fast."
when "go west"
  puts "You tug to your left, but the chains hold fast."

else
   puts "Unknown command."
end
end
```

This doesn't work, I don't think the state :north is being added.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is this in the backend or front-end?

Comment: It was tagged Ruby-On-Rails; I wanted to know if it was back-end or front-end work. If you have an input in ROR, it has to be processed on the server, that's all

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: this is for ruby, not rails. My bad on the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. You want instead to have either states (some kind of state machine) :

```
states = [] # list of states or "flags"
loop do
  case gets.chomp
  when 'go north'
    if states.include? :in_north
      puts "You're already north !"
    else
      puts "<You go north ...>"
      states << :in_north # add the state to the pile
    end
  when 'attack'
    if states.include? :in_north # does our pile of state contains :in_north
      puts "You attack the wolf before you !"
    else
      puts "You need to be north to attack !"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you had an extra "end" in your code. fixed it.
BTW, the "<<" operator doesn't work in all ruby versions.
try using "states.push(:north) instead and see how it goes.

```
states = []

case move
when "help"
  help
when "quit"
  quit
when "inventory"
  @inventory
when "go north"
  puts "You hurl your shackled self toward the door. The chains cut into your wrists     and ankles, but you seem to be making progress."
  states << :north # add the state to the pile
when "attack chains"
    if states.include? :north # does our pile of state contains :in_north
      puts "You slam your shackled fists against the wall. You broke the chains!"
    else
      puts "You smash your shackled fists on the ground. Nothing happens."
    end
when "go south"
  puts "Your back shivers against the cold surface of the stone wall."
when "go east"
  puts "You tug to your right, but the chains hold fast."
when "go west"
  puts "You tug to your left, but the chains hold fast."
else
   puts "Unknown command."
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
case [gets.chomp, gets.chomp]
when ["go north", "attack"] then puts "You break the weakened door!"
when ["attack", "go north"] then puts "something else"
end
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for more than a 5-lines script. Please never write code like that.

Comment: Could you please explain why this is a good solution to the question.

Comment: Requires two inputs before processing which may be undesirable.

Comment: @LIUFA, David Unric So far, this is the only answer that does exactly what OP described. If OP wanted to do something else, then it is the OP's responsibility for not making that clear. This is an answer to the OP's question, not anything else.

Comment: @sawa I consider giving bad code to people to be a terrible attitude

Comment: @sawa I apologize for not being clear, I got to review this answer and it has code only with no explanation on what is what an why - hence the comment. Please do not get offended.